# Error in jsp page deployed in tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I am getting an error - Attribute value  "/editor/skin/XXXX/less/YYYY_skin.less"  is quoted with " which must be escaped when used within the value.

I have also used org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false in catalina.properties.

Answer (score 0):

The **strictQuoteEscaping** parameter value was set to **false** in **web.xml** under conf folder of apache-tomcat and it stared working.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>strictQuoteEscaping</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
```